# Putting two images next to each other - minipage?

Tags: graphics, minipage

I hope that I can make use of your valuable crowd intelligence. I am trying to place two images next to each other. However, I am not sure what the best way would be to achieve that. I have tried using minipage. However, I did not manage to get the desired output.
Can someone of you help me? Thank you :)

The code that I have used so far is:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
  \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{modell1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{modell_SF36}
\caption{Messmodelle: Vereinfachte Darstellung für Modell 1}
\label{fig:mod1}
\end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{modell1}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{modell2_SF36}
    \caption{Messmodelle: Vereinfachte Darstellung für Modell 2}
    \label{fig:mod2}
\end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Right now, the two images are one after the other instead of being next to each other. At the moment, it looks like this: 
[image: Right now]

What would you suggest, how can I place the next to each other?

Comment: you have two `figure` environments so they always stack vertically. `\includegraphics` is positioned like a letter so they come next to each other by default, `\includegraphics{a}\includegraphics{b}` will put image b next to image a, but it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: your example produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.` also please try to demonstrate the problem using `example-image` so everyone can run the same test document

Comment: Are you sure all 4 images will fit side by side into the textwidth? From the screenshot they look too wide. Please also clarify: Do you want each pair of images to keep an individual caption (e.g. figure 1 and figure 2)  or do you want subcaptions (e.g. figure 1a and figure 1b)?

Comment: If you know the width, you can use mnipage (figure caption) or subfigure (subcaption).  If you don't know the width, you can use subfloat (subcaption) or measure the width with a savebox.

Comment: @Milkoneva please see the answer

Comment: @jsbibra, as I see, OP is not familiar whit policy of this site. So far he not accept nor up-vote any received answers. That is not nice ... Anyway, +1 for your nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%<------remove demo option in actuals
\usepackage{subfig}%<--------- add or alternatively subfloat and subcaption
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]%
        \centering
        \subfloat[label1a]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} }}%
        \subfloat[label1b]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} }}%
        \subfloat[label1c]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} }}%
        \subfloat[label1d]{{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} }}%
        \caption{four side by side}
        \label{fig:4_models}
    \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```